# Creating a tab bar for multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im building my own web application, which consists of many html pages.

This application has a nav bar, in which the elements on it are loaded from my local database.

I want to create a nav bar, where it is possible to load the content of a html page by clicking on the element in the tab bar. But the nav bar should not load again it stays in its place.

Here's [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jw4mkpj0/6/)!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="/">London</a>
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="/">Paris</a>
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="/">Tokyo</a>
</div>
```

If i click on for example "London" i get underneath the tab tab the London.html content. And when i click on "Paris", i get underneath the content of Paris.html. And the same for Tokyo.

The trick is to load the content and not any more the nav bar.

I am thankful for every help or tip and have a nice day! :)

Comment: set the href value to `/London.html`?

Comment: use fetch or ajax to load the content, and set a click event on the link and use `preventDefault()` on the event object in the click handler.

Comment: You may wan to look into using AJAX.

Comment: bring back the good old days of iFrames and/or frames for content? Honestly, I get the desire to load as little as possible, but browsers are pretty smart.  A small enough header/navigation won't impact page load times -- and odds are reused components will already be cached in the browser.  Trying to avoid a picosecond of extra load doesn't equal the effort involved to work around it.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers!
@Noface it worked like you said!!

Comment: great, just be sure to test it also works with no js too

Comment: That is what i did https://plnkr.co/edit/4GQ2VGOLT8wuhCEP3ZoG?p=preview
How can it work with no js?